# How can I clone a Git repository within a Jenkins DSL job to get and use configuration files before the DSL creates the child jobs?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-job-dsl

I'm working on a project with one repository containing configuration data, and another separate repository housing a Jenkins DSL script.

I would like to use one of the files in the configuration repository within my DSL script to determine the display names of the jobs that are created by the DSL.

However, I am not sure how to go about this. Is there a way to clone the repository in the script before the jobs are created? Has anyone ever done something similar?

[image]

Comment: It might help to [edit] to give an example of how the repo with configuraton data/files is structured, how to get the job names from it, and the expected display names.